# call javascript function from onmouse event within svg file

Tags: javascript, svg, call

I have a svg file that contains this...

```
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 162.7803 192.52)" font-family="'Helvetica'" font-size="11">30</text>
```

If I modify that string so it would look like this instead to be able to call a JavaScript function...

```
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 162.7803 192.52)" onmouseover="MyJavascriptFunction('u32');return true" font-family="'Helvetica'" font-size="11">30</text>
```

Is it then possible to call that JavaScript thats on the same page as the svg file? 
I have tried it but it does not work, the only thing I got to work was a simple alert like this..

```
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 162.7803 192.52)" onmouseover="alert('Hello from JavaScript!')" font-family="'Helvetica'" font-size="11">30</text>
```

the svg file is displayed like this...

```
<embed src="myfile.svg"/>
```

Is this not possible at all or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Dont embed, just include svg body into html. Otherwise your browser would't init event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a easy test case here: http://test.progysm.com/svg/myfile.htm 
where the svg file call MyJavascriptFunction which is defined inside myfile.htm
from the onmouseover event in myfile.svg.

All you need to use is a reference to the html window. I used "top", maybe you could use "parent" too:

```
<t onmouseover="top.MyJavascriptFunction('u32');return true">...</t>
```

My script inside mytest.htm:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MyJavascriptFunction(s) {
  console.log(s);
}
</script>
```

SVG has attributes: xmlns, width, height and viewport.

Comment: Thanks, parent worked fine, do you by any chance know if x and y positions on the page are treated diferently when using a svg and JavaScript in order to determine the position of the cursor on the svg? I need to use the ability to call a JavaScript function which you helped me with, that JavaScript should display a div, I have the JavaScript function for that but it does not work as expected together with the svg file, but if I use the same script on a html link it works as expected..

Comment: I've updated my test case to send the evt object and it seems like clientX, clientY, pageX, pageY inside the evt object are relative to the SVG container, so I guess, in the html file, you would need to add that to the <embed> x,y position.

Comment: Hmm, I see that it also depends on where I with the cursor enters the svg file, if I for example enter the svg file from the lower right corner and move the cursor and trigger the onmouseover event, then the div is displayed in the lower right corner. But if I enter the upper right corner of the svg file and trigger the same onmouseover event, then the div is displayed in the upper right corner instead.... this makes it very hard and might even impossible to Place the div where I want them to be, which is to the right side of the actual svg "link" with the onmouse over event.... :(